# CloudPages editor is blank. Loads the header but the editor itself never loads any content

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage

I'm trying to edit a cloud page created by my colleague. I can view the live page fine. But when I try to edit the page in the CloudPages editor the editor is blank.

I can see the editor page header etc. But the actual editor area below remains a blank and never loads anything.

Using the browser 'inspect element' I can see where the editor should be is just an empty div.

```
<div data-view="editor-main">
<div class="cp-cloud-editor-container">
<div data-view="editor" class="fuelux">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried multiple browsers. The result is the same. However everyone else with a login can see the editor on their own computer fine.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my computer specifically or perhaps some problem with my account.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Post edited to include screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the same permissions level of your collegues?

Comment: You've got an apple device ...